# Serverless - AWS S3 Bucket already exists

Tags: yaml, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I am building my first sls app and I am trying to create two buckets. The "LogosBucket" works perfectly. I did the same process to create a second one called "DocumentsBucket" and it fails w/ message: "An error occurred: DocumentsBucket - documents-bucket-dev already exists."

I have looked at the Stack and it is not listed under resources. I am aware of this issue happening w/ bucket events but I don't think that is my case. It feels like a very simple oversight but I am a bit lost.

Here is my serverless.yml file:

```
    iamRoleStatements:
    - ${file(iam/LogosBucketIAM.yml):LogosBucketIAM}
    - ${file(iam/DocumentsBucketIAM.yml):DocumentsBucketIAM}

resources:
  Resources:
    LogosBucket: ${file(resources/LogosBucket.yml):LogosBucket}
    LogosBucketPolicy: ${file(resources/LogosBucket.yml):LogosBucketPolicy}
    DocumentsBucket: ${file(resources/DocumentsBucket.yml):DocumentsBucket}
    DocumentsBucketPolicy: ${file(resources/DocumentsBucket.yml):DocumentsBucketPolicy}

...

custom:
  LogosBucket:
    name: logos-bucket-${self:provider.stage}
  DocumentsBucket:
    name: documents-bucket-${self:provider.stage}
```

DocumentsBucketIAM.yml:

```
DocumentsBucketIAM:
  Effect: Allow
  Action:
    - s3:PutObject
  Resource: arn:aws:s3:::${self:custom.DocumentsBucket.name}/*
```

LogosBucketIAM.yml:

```
LogosBucketIAM:
  Effect: Allow
  Action:
    - s3:PutObject
  Resource: arn:aws:s3:::${self:custom.LogosBucket.name}/*
```

DocumentsBucket.yml:

```
DocumentsBucket:
  Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
  Properties:
    BucketName: ${self:custom.DocumentsBucket.name}

DocumentsBucketPolicy:
  Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
  Properties:
    Bucket: !Ref DocumentsBucket
    PolicyDocument:
      Statement:
        - Sid: PublicRead
          Effect: Allow
          Principal: '*'
          Action:
            - s3:GetObject
          Resource: arn:aws:s3:::${self:custom.DocumentsBucket.name}/*
```

LogosBucket.yml:

```
LogosBucket:
  Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
  Properties:
    BucketName: ${self:custom.LogosBucket.name}

LogosBucketPolicy:
  Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
  Properties:
    Bucket: !Ref LogosBucket
    PolicyDocument:
      Statement:
        - Sid: PublicRead
          Effect: Allow
          Principal: '*'
          Action:
            - s3:GetObject
          Resource: arn:aws:s3:::${self:custom.LogosBucket.name}/*
```

I would appreciate any help and/or tips to debug sls. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

S3 is a universal namespace, meaning each S3 bucket you create must have a unique name that is not being used by anyone else in the world. This is because your bucket name makes up part of your S3 url, which must be unique.

Comment: Thank you! That was it.